# Show that $u$ and $v$ are solutions of the wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Suppose that $u = u(x, t)$ and $v = v(x, t)$ have partial derivatives as follows:
$$u_t=-v_x \quad\text{and}\quad v_t=-u_x.$$
Show that $u$ and $v$ are solutions of the wave equation:
$$u_{tt}=u_{xx}.$$

**My solution effort:**
taking derivative of $v_t=-u_x$ w.r.t $x$, $v_{xt}=-u_{xx}$, we get $u_{xx}=-v_{xt}$. Similiarly; $u_{tt}=-v_{xt}$. Then $u_{tt}=u_{xx}$.

Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

If $v$ is a $C^2$ function, then $v_{xt}=v_{tx}$ (Schwaz's theorem) and you are right.

Comment: We don' t know that $v$ is a $C^2$ function. It is not given in the question. Then, how can we show that $u$ and $v$ are solutions of the wave equation?

Comment: I suspect that the $C^2$ assumption was implicit in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This reduces to show that
$$v_{tx} = v_{xt}$$
This is true (Schwarz's theorem) as soon as your function $v$ admits a second derivative (you don't need $C^2$ assumption).